# log in as another user in jira data center

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I clicked on gg "Users" and I typed a specific user name and I was trying to login as that user but the problem is that I didn't find log in as user under the three dots. Here is a screenshot of the menu that I found.

[image]

Anyone knows how to log in as another user in Jira data center?